# Browsers capabilities for Webdriver - full list

Tags: selenium, webdriver, webdriver-io, desiredcapabilities

Hi do you know where I can find a full list of browsers capabilities to use with Webdriver protocol?

I need to undestand this for using better Webdriver.io, but any Webdriver client should use the same list I suppose.

For instance in the wdio.conf.js, for Chrome, we can add

```
'chromeOptions': {
                args: ['--start-fullscreen']
}
```

What other args are supported - a full list - and what other options, besides args are available.

Could not find a full list for all main browsers: chrome, safari, firefox, edge...

Thanks

UPDATE: to be honest, I've been searching online quite a bit but the full list of args is not easy to find (besides the one for chrome). So, I'll leave this as answered and once I find more info I'll update the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is spread across a few different sites.

For `chromeOptions`, it looks like you want this list:

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities

Firefox:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities/firefoxOptions

Safari:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/safari/SafariOptions.html

Edge:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/edge/EdgeDriver.html

Internet explorer:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerOptions.html

Comment: Thanks Christine, to be honest, besides for Chrome, I cannot see the full list of accepted `args` for the other browsers. Am I missing them? For Chrome here it is indeed: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: @Miha On the seleniumhq pages (used for Safari, Edge, and IE), if you scroll down to properties and methods, you can see all of the capabilities detailed there. These are the pages that I personally use when I need to reference capabilities. Some browsers have specific syntax such as `AddAdditionalCapability` or options get set using Properties.

Comment: thanks @Christine, I'll give it a try. Maybe I was wrong to look only for the `args` list.

Answer (score 2):

W3C defines the common [WebDriver capabilites](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#capabilities) each implementation must support.

*(W3C Working Draft 22 November 2021)*

- `browserName`
- `browserVersion`
- `platformName`
- `acceptInsecureCerts`
- `pageLoadStrategy`
- `proxy`
- `setWindowRect`
- `timeouts`
- `strictFileInteractability`
- `unhandledPromptBehavior`